# data binding issue with polymer template inside angular app

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I copied and paste code from https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html in my angular app. Anything inside of the template tag is not rendering.

```
<dom-module id="employee-list">
  <template>

    <div> Employee list: </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
        <div>First name: <span>{{item.first}}</span></div>
        <div>Last name: <span>{{item.last}}</span></div>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'employee-list',
      ready: function() {
        this.employees = [
            {first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith'},
            {first: 'Sally', last: 'Johnson'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Are you including Polymer when you declare this element? Are you importing this element correctly in index.html or within another element? Could you post some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a typo. I misspelled the template name.